# Sitcore 8 Update 2 | Unable to find search API's

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore8

I am trying to create a custom poco for solr in sitecore 8.I have referenced all dlls given in the solr support package.For some reason I am not able to find IndexField Attribute and also extensions like Page,GetResults ,Filter on GetQueryable as below.Any idea would help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq` reference.

Just add that reference to your project and all should be fine.

Also you don't need to add "_t" and other suffixes for your index field attributes.